# MAKING ITMSP- looking up software id causing erro

Tags: build, ipa

i was trying to move my ipa to Testflight for testing via transporter.

During loading of the ipa file, i can see this message appears

**"MAKING ITMSP- looking up software id causing error" **

and Transporter ended with a status "6449955672---.itmsp".

There is no error log created in Transporter folder.

fyi - i have created this ipa previously and succesfully uploaded to Transporter

i have searched Goolge and stackovrFlow - most of the error are appname, bundle ID but none of them mentioned Software ID

Steps taken to produce this error
generate the ipa using this command as usual.
flutter build ipa --obfuscate --split-debug-info=v1.2.3

drag the ipa to Trnsporter.

The message from the ipa build follows:

Archiving com.runninghour.RH...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: U25SHR5X38
Running Xcode build...
└─Compiling, linking and signing...                        51.9s
Xcode archive done.                                         1199.2s
Built /Volumes/Toshiba/cguanguan_flutterapp/rh/build/ios/archive/Runner.xcarchive.

[✓] App Settings Validation
• Version Number: ""
• Build Number: ""
• Display Name: xxxxxxxx
• Deployment Target: 12.0
• Bundle Identifier: com.runninghour.rh

[!] App Icon and Launch Image Assets Validation
! App icon is set to the default placeholder icon. Replace with unique icons.

To update the settings, please refer to https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/ios

Building App Store IPA...                                         149.5s
Built IPA to /Volumes/Toshiba/cguanguan_flutterapp/rh/build/ios/ipa.
To upload to the App Store either:
1. Drag and drop the "build/ios/ipa/*.ipa" bundle into the Apple Transporter macOS app https://apps.apple.com/us/app/transporter/id1450874784
2. Run "xcrun altool --upload-app --type ios -f build/ios/ipa/*.ipa --apiKey your_api_key --apiIssuer your_issuer_id".
See "man altool" for details about how to authenticate with the App Store Connect API key.